# I want to set up my email reminder on a bi-weekly basis in access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I need help creating some code that will send email reminders once every two weeks. I already have code that send email reminders, but it sends the emails once everyday. That can be very annoying to the users

Here is my vba code from access:

```
 Function GenerateEmail(MySQL As String)
 'On Error GoTo Exit_Function:
  Dim oOutLook As Outlook.Application
  Dim oEmailAddress As MailItem
  Dim MyEmpName As String
  Dim MyEquip As String
  Dim MyModel As String
  Dim MyAsset As String
  Dim MySerial As String
  Dim rs As Recordset
  Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(MySQL)
 If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
rs.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF
If IsNull(rs!EmailAddress) Then
        rs.MoveNext
Else
If oOutLook Is Nothing Then
Set oOutLook = New Outlook.Application
End If
 Set oEmailAddressItem = oOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
 With oEmailAddressItem

           MyEmpName = DLookup("EmpName", "Employees", "[EmpID]= " & rs!EmpName)
            MyEquip = rs!EquipmentType
            MyModel = rs!ModelNo
            MyAsset = rs!AssetNo
            MySerial = rs!SerialNo
            .To = "another@.com;another@.com;another@.com"
            .Subject = "Calibration that's due between 1 to 11 months"
            .Body = "Calibration ID: " & rs!RecordID & vbCr & _
                    "Location: " & rs!CalLocation & vbCr & _
                   "Requirement: " & rs!CalRequirement & vbCr & _
                   "Employee: " & MyEmpName & vbCr & _
                   "Name: " & MyEquip & vbCr & _
                   "Serial No.: " & MySerial & vbCr & _
                   "Model No.: " & MyModel & vbCr & _
                   "Asset No.: " & MyAsset & vbCr & _
                   "Due Date : " & rs!CalUpcomingDate & vbCr & vbCr & _
                   "This email is auto generated. Please Do Not Replay!"
            'MyEmpName = DLookup("EmpName", "Employees", "[EmpID]= " & rs!EmpName)
            '.To = rs!EmailAddress
            '.Subject = "Task due in between 1st and 11th month reminder for " & MyEmpName
            '.Body = "Task ID: " & rs!RecordID & vbCr & _
                   '"Task Name: " & rs!TaskName & vbCr & _
                   '"Employees: " & MyEmpName & vbCr & _
                  ' "Task Due: " & rs!CalUpcomingDate & vbCr & vbCr & _
                   '"This email is auto generated from Task Database. Please Do Not Replay!"
             .Display
             '.Send
             ' rs.Edit
             ' rs!DateEmailSent = Date
             ' rs.Update
      End With
      Set oEmailAddressItem = Nothing
      Set oOutLook = Nothing
      rs.MoveNext
  End If
Loop
Else
'do nothing
End If
rs.Close
Exit_Function:
Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: Add a field to your table with the _Sent_ date, then filter for _Sent_ dates being Null or older than two weeks. For this recordset update _Sent_ to `Date()`.

Comment: This will work. The reason I'm asking is because I have a list of Calibrations that have not been started are approaching the due date. I want to remind the users every two weeks. Informing them about each calibrations and their due date so they can always be alert.

Comment: Is  calibarationDate list in other table, or they are fields in the same record?

Comment: If you're referring to the SerialNo, ModelNo, AssetNo, and Equip than no. Those fields are in the equipment table. The due date employee, location, and ID is in the calibration table. I created a query for those records to create a list of calibrations that have the status of "Not Started". I'm trying to send that list to users as a email reminder once every two weeks. I need to know if I need some type of vba code in my GenerateEmail that will let the system know to only send this list once every two weeks.

Comment: @Gustav what code are you referring to when you mention update Sent to Date(). Are you referring to rs!DateEmailSent = Date or the query?

Comment: @Gustav is this correct for the criteria in the query `<Date()-14`

Comment: @M.Hassan, what do you think?

Comment: you have to loop over the calibration list and check if (date() -[due date] = 14) and ( not_started)

Comment: @M.Hassan do I put that in my query or my vba code

Comment: @M.Hassan, also what do you mean by loop over? Do I input if (date() -[due date] = 14) and ( not_started) under the loop in my vba code?

Comment: I mean you  OpenRecordset (your_caliberation_list_sql) , and the loop over is (Do Until rs.EOF). I suggest re-engineer your code and divide your procedure to two procedures. The first one is looping using rs.EOF and call sendEmail() (the second). The second one is the new sendEmail procedure that conatain all your email logic.

Comment: @M.Hassan  Can you show me an example pretty please?

Comment: Ok, first can you edit your question and dump the structure of your tables.

Comment: Can you chat with me

Comment: @M.Hassan, can you show me an example? Please. When you say dump my table are you referring to my vba code or an actually table in my database.

Comment: @M.Hassan, how do I chat with you?

Comment: yes, i refer to your actual code. i want to the structure of calibaration table to write eample.

Comment: @M.Hassan, The vba code is calling from a query that I created with a relationship between my Equipment table and Calibration table

Comment: have a look for http://pasted.co/7a1b2fc2 . It contain the main skeleton to the code.

Comment: @M.Hassan, when I test out the code I get this error stating that the oEmailAddressItem is variable not defined.

Comment: This variable is in your code, modify the code as you wish, i can't run it bez i didn't have the table structure.just it is the skeleton of logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you had the right idea once - and @Gustav pointed out the solution.

You first need to uncomment out the lines:

```
' rs.Edit
' rs!DateEmailSent = Date
' rs.Update
```

Then change what happens when you process each email address:

> **Suggested new look of your program:**

```
rs.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF

    If Not IsNull(rs!EmailAddress) Then

        ' Only Send Emails if never been sent before - or past 14 days since last one'
         If (IsNull(rs!DateEmailSent)) Or DateDiff("d", rs!DateEmailSent, Date) >= 14 Then

            If oOutLook Is Nothing Then
                Set oOutLook = New Outlook.Application
            End If
            Set oEmailAddressItem = oOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

            ' ... rest of email processing '
            ' .................... '

            .Display
            .Send

            ' Make sure to record that reminder was sent '
             rs.Edit
             rs!DateEmailSent = Date
             rs.Update

            ' Only do this if this has been set '
            Set oEmailAddressItem = Nothing
         End If
    End If

    rs.MoveNext
Loop

' Do this at end '
Set oOutLook = Nothing
```

Comment: That pretty much covers it.

Comment: Thank you @dbmitch

Comment: @dbmitch. Everything works now. I have another question. I want to include 2 weeks approaching LeadDate. How do I go about doing that.

Comment: Should I know what LeadDate is and how you want to include it? As a new field? As a new criteria? Combine with other criteria? You should probably start a new question or update above one if it's trivial.

Comment: @dbmitch. Lead Time is the time between the initiation and completion of a production process. I call it Lead Date, because I create some code that calculated that change to a date. Lead Date is a field I created in a query. 
If a Calibration was due on 9/15/2016 I will subtract the lead time from that due date. Lead time can be measure up to 3 weeks, 6 weeks, 9 weeks, 12 weeks, etc. Once you have that calculation than I want to send a reminder for a calibration 2 weeks approaching the LeadDate. Does this makes any sense to you?

Comment: Sure - I just don't see any field like LeadTime or LeadDate in your query. It souns like it should be a different field and perhaps even a different function. Are you thinking of using same function?

Comment: @dbmitch,
SELECT CalibrationRecord.RecordID, CalibrationRecord.CalRequirement, CalibrationRecord.CalStatus, CalibrationRecord.CalLocation, Equipment.EquipmentType, Equipment.SerialNo, Equipment.ModelNo, Equipment.AssetNo, CalibrationRecord.EmpName, Employees.EmailAddress, CalibrationRecord.LastCalDate, CalibrationRecord.CalTimeInterval, CalibrationRecord.UOM

Comment: DateAdd(IIf([CalibrationRecord]![UOM]="days","d",IIf([CalibrationRecord]![UOM]="month","m","yyyy")),[CalTimeInterval],[LastCalDate]) AS CalUpcomingDate, CalibrationRecord.DateEmailSent, DateAdd(IIf([Equipment]![UOM]="weeks","ww"),-[LeadInterval],[CalUpcomingDate]) AS LeadDate
FROM Equipment INNER JOIN (Employees INNER JOIN CalibrationRecord ON Employees.EmpID = CalibrationRecord.EmpName) ON Equipment.ItemID = CalibrationRecord.EquipItemID

Comment: WHERE (((CalibrationRecord.CalStatus)="Not Started") AND ((Employees.EmailAddress) Is Not Null) AND ((CalibrationRecord.CalTimeInterval) Between 6 And 9) AND ((CalibrationRecord.UOM) Like "month") AND ((Employees.EmpName) Not Like "MFGUSER")) OR (((CalibrationRecord.UOM) Like "days"));

Comment: @dbmitch. Above is the query that I am using.

Comment: I'd suggest you start a new question or edit your question above and append the query and new question. Posting code in comments is unreadable